# Node.js restful webservice using express and mongoose. Routing not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, api, express

I'm trying to build a RESTful webservice following this tutorial: 
https://www.codementor.io/olatundegaruba/nodejs-restful-apis-in-10-minutes-q0sgsfhbd

It's not working returning me a **CANNOT GET/ reports** error...
I'm trying to learn node.js and I can't find the error anywhere and everything I tried didn't work.

Also, when I call the server, it reaches to index.js which prints a "HEY". Wasn't this supposed to reach server.js first?

Here is my code:

Server.js

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
port = process.env.PORT || 3000,
mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Report = require('./api/models/reportModel.js'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/server');


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


var routes = require('./api/routes/reportRoute.js');
routes(app);



app.listen(port);


console.log('Report RESTful API server started on: ' + port);
```

reportRoute.js

```
  'use strict';
  module.exports = function(app) {
  var reports = require('../controllers/reportController.js');


    // report Routes
  app.route('/reports')
    .get(reports.list_all_reports)
    .post(reports.create_a_report);


  app.route('/reports/:reportId').get(reports.read_a_report)
    .put(reports.update_a_report)
    .delete(reports.delete_a_report);
};
```

reportController.js

```
    'use strict';


var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Report = mongoose.model('Reports');

exports.list_all_reports = function(req, res) {
  Report.find({}, function(err, report) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
    res.json(report);
  });
};




exports.create_a_report = function(req, res) {
  var new_report = new Report(req.body);
  new_report.save(function(err, report) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
    res.json(report);
  });
};


exports.read_a_report = function(req, res) {
  Report.findById(req.params.reportId, function(err, report) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
    res.json(report);
  });
};


exports.update_a_report = function(req, report) {
  Report.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.taskId}, req.body, { new: true }, function(err, report) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
    res.json(report);
  });
};


exports.delete_a_report = function(req, res) {


  Report.remove({
    _id: req.params.reportId
  }, function(err, report) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
    res.json({ message: 'Report successfully deleted' });
  });
};
```

Thank you for your help...

EDIT:

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var route = require('./api/routes/reportRoute');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('HEY!');
})
app.listen(3000, function(){console.log('Server running on port 3000')});
```

Comment: is that all code you have written. I think you are not connect router file correctly

Comment: What is missing for my router?

Comment: to make this simple just edit in app.js. after `app.use(bodyParser.json());` add `app.get('/test', function(req, res) { res.jsonp({data : 'hello'});})` then try localhost:port/test and tell us what happend?

Comment: it returns **Cannot GET /test**. I'm afraid it is not reaching server.js...

Comment: I think your server file has the issue.

Comment: try to run this file in my [gist](https://gist.github.com/viranmalaka/d635b3a9f69bc1e88f1019c024c398f6)

Comment: Problem solved, the problem was in my package.json, on "start" key. I had to change it to server.js, or else it would never reach it. Thank you everyone for your help.

Comment: oho... Nice to here.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted your `reportController.js` but this problem will occur if the function list_all_reports does not set a response body. For example, adding

```
res.json({hello: "world"});
```

to the handler function should make it work.

Comment: just added it... thank you for your answer. My function is returning **report**
but my database is empty, could this be the problem?

Comment: Can you replace the exports.list_all_reports function with `res.json({hello: "world"});` just to do a sanity check?

Comment: Just tried this, didn't work... Got the same response: CANNOT GET/ reports